# My XPATH expression does not work properly

Tags: xml, xpath

I use this xpath expression to list all "NON TEST" items:

```
/Items/Item[State!='TEST']/Name
```

Normally input XML looks like this and everything works fine:

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Name>Item1</Name>
    <State>ACTIVE</State>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>Item2</Name>
    <State>TEST</State>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

But when Item miss State element the xpath expression selects nothing:

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Name>Item1</Name>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>Item2</Name>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Please, how should I change my xpath expression so that it also works when State element does not exists? If State element does not exists Item is considered as "NON TEST" item. I have no option to change xml structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following expression:

```
/Items/Item[not(State='TEST')]/Name
```

The difference is that `State!='TEST'` selects those items having any `State` element whose string value is not equal to `TEST`, while `not(State='TEST')` selects all items not having a `State` element whose string value is equal to `TEST` (whether `State` exists or not). It's a subtle but significant difference.

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans):

> If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a string,
>   then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the
>   node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the
>   string-value of the node and the other string is true.

Furthermore, imagine the following input:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Name>Item1</Name>
        <State>blah</State>
        <State>TEST</State>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>Item2</Name>
        <State>TEST</State>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

This expression:

```
/Items/Item[State!='TEST']/Name
```

...will select the first `Item`'s `Name` element, because it contains *at least one* `State` element not having a value of `TEST`.

However, this expression:

```
/Items/Item[not(State='TEST')]/Name
```

...selects no items. This second form is very often what you want.

See this note [from the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans):

> **NOTE:** If `$x` is bound to a node-set, then `$x="foo"` does not mean the
>   same as `not($x!="foo")`: the former is true if and only if *some* node in
>   `$x` has the string-value `foo`; the latter is true if and only if *all*
>   nodes in `$x` have the string-value `foo`.

Comment: +1, good answer. Are you sure though about the statement "`State!='TEST'` selects those items whose (first) State element does not have a value equal to TEST"? I think it selects those items that have *any* `State` child element whole value is not equal to 'TEST'. In other words, I believe the node tests in the comparison are not collapsed to string values so soon as to preclude existential comparisons.